# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application connected to a SQL database and it's
working perfectly when I launch it from Visual Studio with the IIS
Express profile.

I'm trying for more than a week just to publish it on IIS on my dev machine and I keep getting the error

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

I've done the below troubleshooting and searched for more with no result.

1. I make sure that my Windows account is a member of the administrators and IIS_users.
2. Install from Windows feature IIS services as attached picture.
3. Install SDK and .NET and runtime packages.
4. Made sure that the .NET Framework version value is v4.0

Note: after publishing to a folder, I deleted the `web.config` file since it's .NET Core 3.1.
note2: I have added a screenshot of my IIS how it looks after adding the website on it.

Please guide me on how could I fix this and many thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231285/net-core-publishing-to-iis-problems-403-14

Comment: thank you Rahul for answering but it didn't work !

Comment: Your information is a bit poor. Here you can find some general debugging information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-403-14-forbidden-webpage. But I would recommend adding more details to your question.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly make sure your application pool has the enough permission to access the folder which you have used in your application. More details about how to set the IIS application pool permission, you could refer to this [article](https://support.pkware.com/home/smar/latest/sem-knowledge-base/kb-granting-folder-permissions-to-iis-application-pools).

Comment: I don't know if this will help but if I created a new web application and publish it to IIS and it works.

Comment: so if I keep the generated web.config file I'm getting a 404 error that page cannot be found and if I delete it im getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: If you delete the web.config, that means it will try browse the file which stroed in the folder. Normally, the IIS don't have the permission to access it. I suggest you could re-check your web.config to make sure the setting is right.